# how to manage state of the check boxes displaying in multiple bootstrap cards

Tags: reactjs

On calling API I got multiple JSON objects (it could be 2,3,6 or some other count) which contains the array of string with the length of more than 6000  records in each object. I need to display these records in a bootstrap card.

For example, if I got 2 JSON object then 2 cards should be displayed and each bootstrap card contains the records' name with the checkboxes.

So, how can I manage the state of these checkboxes let say if I click on cardb apply button then only cardb checked checkboxes and the name of the card i.e., "cardb" should be captured somewhere so that I can use this info for further API calling.

Can someone please help me out in this?

Main.JSX

```
render() {
    return (
      <main
        role="main"
        className="flex-shrink-0">
        <div className="container">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleWidgetsCardFormSubmit}>
            <div className="row flex-row flex-nowrap wc-main-div-scroll">
              {this.displayWidgetsCard()}
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </main>
    );
  }

 displayWidgetsCard() {
    if (this.state.displayWidgetsCard === true) {
      console.log("Total widgets card to show: ",this.state.cardCount.length);
      let t = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < this.state.cardCount.length; i++) {
        t.push(
          <Card
            key={this.state.cardCount[i].cardname}
            cardName={this.state.cardCount[i].cardname}
            recordCount={this.state.cardCount[i].count}
            createCheckboxes={this.createCheckboxes3(this.state.cardCount[i].recordsArr)}
          />
        );
      }
      return t;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    this.selectedCheckboxes3 = new Set();
  };

   toggleCheckbox3 = label => {
    if (this.selectedCheckboxes3.has(label)) {
      this.selectedCheckboxes3.delete(label);
    } else {
      this.selectedCheckboxes3.add(label);
    }
  };
  createCheckbox3 = label => (
    <Checkbox
      label={label}
      handleCheckboxChange={this.toggleCheckbox3}
      key={label}
    />
  );

  createCheckboxes3 = array1 => array1.map(this.createCheckbox3);
```

Card.JSX

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    const { cardName, createCheckboxes, recordCount } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="col-4">
        <div className="card wc-dim border-dark sh">
          <div className="card-header">
            <b>
              {cardName}
              {" (" + recordCount + ")"}
            </b>
            <div className="input-group mt-2">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control search-form"
                placeholder="Search"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="card-body wc-scroll">
            <div className="card-text">{createCheckboxes}</div>
          </div>
          <div className="card-footer bg-transparent">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="btn-right">
              Apply
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried, and the code.

Comment: Each `checkbox` should have a unique id. Whenever a `checkbox` is checked, save the `id` in local state/redux and use this when `apply` is clicked.

Comment: I have updated the post with code